# parsing textarea input with PHP as if its a csv?

Tags: php, csv, input

i'm trying to make a site where people paste a CSV file directly into a textarea (say its called "original-text") and parse it, with my script then generating something from that. i know how to parse a csv file on the server (using fgetcsv) but not how to get the input from a POST variable INTO that fgetcsv. so far i've tried something like this, to no avail:

```
$file_handle = fopen("php://input", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle);
    echo $line_of_text[0] . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`fgetcsv()` has a cousin named [**str_getcsv()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) that should do exactly what you need. As so often, wonderfully named (once without, once with underscore). Ah well! But we still love PHP, don't we.

Example (with no sanitation!!! I can't see any necessary at this point, though.)

```
$array_csv = str_getcsv($_POST["csv"]);
```

Comment: Thanks Pekka! small thing though - my host is only running PHP 5.2.x, which doesnt support this function... is there another easy way to do something like this, short of asking them to upgrade?

Comment: @yonation Ah, I didn't see that it's >= 5.3.0. Check out the user comments in the manual page, there are a number of replacement functions. I'm sure you'll find one that fits.

Comment: Interesting add-on - what it it's a multiline CSV? Does it still work?

Answer (score 2):

[Pekka's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2246667/1127583) works for a single line of CSV data. If users enter multiple lines of CSV data you'll have to implode this first into an array ('$lines' in the example below) and then iterate through that and parse each line with str_getcsv:

```
$array_csv = array();
  $lines = explode("\n", $_POST["csv"]);
  foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $array_csv[] = str_getcsv($line);
  }
}
```

See: [parse csv to multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8353397/1127583)

Comment: you should use `PHP_EOL` instead of `"\n"` to work in any OS